# Магия модели Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть модель Post

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class Post extends Model
{
    use Sluggable;

    const IS_DRAFT = 0;
    const IS_PUBLIC = 1;

    protected $fillable = ['title','content', 'date', 'description'];



    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }


    public function getComments()
    {
        return $this->comments()->where('status', 1)->get();
    }
}
```

В контроллере, ни к какой метод не вызывается, а только идёт обращение ко всей модели, нужной статье

```
public function show($slug)
    {
        $post = Post::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();

        return view('pages.show', compact('post'));

    }
```

И в виде, вызывается метод **$post->getComments**, как этот метод попал в вид, если в контроллере, его не передавали?
или когда идёт любое обращение к классу, таким способом **Post::** то в переменную вшиваются все методы?

Answer (score 1):

Ты в контроллере получил экземпляр модели `Post` и передаешь этот экземпляр в вод. И нет разницы, где ты используешь этот экземпляр со всеми его методами - в контроллере, виде, консольной команде, задаче, обработчике события и т.д.
Ну и еще момент. Раз уж это метод класса, то и вызавать его надо как метод: **$post->getComments()**

Comment: Как я его получил, если обычно, через двоеточие, идёт обращение к статическим методам, без создания экземпляра?

Comment: Статические методы laravel используют внутри себя вызов new static() и возвращают экземпляр)) Почитаю тему про позднее статическое связывание